# How can I solve "Your connection is not privat"?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I ran my virtual machine by the command "vagrant up" and it's ok. "vagrant ssh" work good. But when I hit this URL laravel58.dev it's give me error your connection is not private. Please help to solve me this problem.

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"

memory: 2048

cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: 'E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel58'
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel58

sites:
    - map: laravel58.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/laravel58/public

databases:
    - laravel58

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

Comment: If you are using chrome, you can't use `.dev` domains withtout https. https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https

Comment: So there have any way to redirect https  locally?

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.dev` tld has been brought, so from Chrome (^v63) all .dev urls will be forced to https.

So either you have to change your website to use https or just change the domain to something like `.test`.

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome, you can't use `.dev` domains withtout https.

Here is an [Article](https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https) talking about it.

One solution would be to disable security on chrome, you have 2 options:

- Running Chrome with the --ignore-certificate-errors command line flag

or

- Chrome menu > Settings > Advanced > Protect you and your device from dangerous sites > Turn off.

But i wouldn't advise it. Better use another domain for development like `.lcl` or `.local`

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks.